# How to protect the password of a SQlite Database stored inside VB.NET code?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Working on VB.Net with SQLite 3 I create the database with

```
Dim conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDataBase.sqlite; Version=3;foreign keys=true")
conn.SetPassword("MyStrongPassword")
```

Before the first Open()

Then everytime I open another connection I use

```
Dim conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDataBase.sqlite;Version=3;Password=MyStrongPassword;foreign keys=true")
```

I don't need a supreme level of protection but I think when I create the software installer maybe one user can sneak into the .exe code and take care of the plain text "MyStrongPassword"

**It is possible to obfuscate the text? Maybe with a trick joining parts of a String?**

```
Variable1 = "ThisIsMypart"
Variable2 = "OfAStrongProtection"
Variable3 = "ForPassword"
```

**And then manipulate Variable1, Variable2, Variable3 to create the right password?**

Comment: Creating a connection object that way does not create a database, it connects you to a db.  I guess you are asking about protecting the password?

Comment: @Plutonix after de Dim I use a block of Try Using.... with various "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS". I just ommit that part on the question. Yes, I ask about protect the password.

Comment: The answer is that it is very simple to crack open a NET app and read the source code.  Having the DB encrypted does prevent someone from opening the DB in a UI Browser tool outside your app.

Comment: @Plutonix. I understand. Anyway if I open the myprogram.exe file and check the text inside I don´t see any clue of the database password. So I think the secutiry is fine for my need

Comment: Open it with http://ilspy.net/ and you can read it like source code

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for the link.